# Convert RBG to CMYK with use of ICC profile in PHP

Tags: php, linux, rgb, cmyk, color-profile

I am currently building an online APP which allows users to pick a color for text from a usual javascript color picker. I want to convert the returned value to CMYK and I know there is not one simple run-of-the-mill method to achieve this, given there are ICC profiles and all that.

I still want to achieve a relatively useful conversion the way "most" users know from Photoshop. The profiles I want to use are "AdobeRGB" for the RGB colorspace, and "Coated Fogra39" for the CMYK colorspace.

What I want to know is, if there is any method to convert single color values from one colorspace to the other, by utilizing these two ICC profiles (which I have downloaded). There are methods to convert entire images with ImageMagick, but I am dying trying to find a way to just calculate from one color value to the other.
I am also inclined to use other means of achieving this goal if there are any ideas out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Imagick::setImageColorSpace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php)

Here's a [tutorial](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/cmyk-rgb-and-php)

Also i must warn you cmyk profile is for printing not for screening they will be differences and you can't calculate the same as rgb ( rgb misses the black thing ) an example for black ( everyone know's this color )
RGB  Black : 0, 0, 0,
CMYK Black: 100%;
But they 100% key doesn't work the same on some printers you only need 100% on others like the one that i use a roland sp 540i i make a combination of colors to produce different types of black based on what i need because 100%key will not produce the black that everyone knows and you can test it even in photoshop / corel draw to see a difference if your screen helps u.

Other examples:

- Registration Black | C100 M100 Y100 K100
- Neutral Rich Black (also known as Rich Black) | C40 M30 Y30 K100
- Flat Black | C0 M0 Y0 K100 - This black is just made up of 100% of the black channel, with no other ink in the mix. Also known as Standard black.
- Designer Black | C70 M50 Y30 K100 Pantone® Process Black | Spot-Color/’K100′ : This
  black is available as Pantone® Process Black C (coated), U,
  (Uncoated) and M (Matt).
- Cool Black (also known as Black Bump) | C50 M0 Y0 K100 : This is the general-mix, but this black can also be comprised [typically] of between 20%-80% cyan.
- Golden Black | C0 M0 Y60 K100 : This is the general-mix, but this black can also be
  comprised [typically] of between 20%-80% yellow.
- Warm Black | C0 M60 Y0 K100 : This is the general-mix, but this black can also be
  comprised [typically] of between 20%-80% magenta.

So you see CMYK is very different from rgb space because is used for printing and that means you will have trouble if you don't know how it works.

Update: ICC Profiles are for monitors not for printing ..

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bogdan, but the specified links do not help much. I am somehow trying to achieve the conversion that Photoshop (or better, Illustrator) uses in its color picker. There, e.g. rgb(255, 0, 0) turns into cmyk(0, 88.04, 89.07, 0) and rgb(0, 255, 255) turns into cmyk(61.57, 0, 15.79, 0).

Do you believe it's possible to achieve a similar conversion somehow? Or is this a secret of Adobe's methods?
Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: the second link from my reply provides a few techniques on how to make the conversion. but i dunno how adobe calculates the colors. Probably they are more equations for this.

Comment: Her's a topic on adobe about this i think https://forums.adobe.com/message/3078609

Comment: Thanks again - it seems I'll have to find a custom solution then or ask one of my mathematician friends to help me on this one.

Comment: yeah that could do.. or you could find a print shop in your town and ask them more about the cmyk profile. a typography would be the best place to learn more about this one that uses really old machines where they mix colors manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a Photoshop image that consists of a series of gradients that emulate a subset of all RGB colors and then save this as a CMYK (say uncompressed TIFF so you can use the image like a lookup table). Read the color values and based on those create a set of equations that can extrapolate the destination CMYK from a lookup in this image, although that is a lot of effort, tried once and abandoned, somewhat complex... Or, give the user a reduced set of combinations and store those in a table, like all the #000 -- #fff combinations, if that is acceptable for you.

RGB -- CMYK conversion is far from simple, that's why Adobe progs cost money...

Answer (score 1):

To just answer the question in your Title:

#### Convert RBG to CMYK with use of ICC profile in PHP

You can use the commandline via a `system()` call:

```
<?php
system('convert inputfile.png -profile sRGB.icc -profile CoatedFOGRA39.icc -units PixelsPerInch -density 600 outputfile.pdf');
```

This will work on Linux with imagemagick installed

Comment: Very interesting! Can you please give more details? In which OS does this work, LinuxServer? Does the "convert" have to be installed? Is it also possible to use a PDF as the source file?

Comment: I added the info. I am not sure if PDF format will work with the ICC profiles

Comment: As I have now learned, imagemagick will convert vectors to raster graphics!
Therefore the example from PNG to PDF will work fine, you show how to set the resolution by density, 600 will give a good quality.
So I have to be satisfied with raster in the result PDF or look for another way.